# Expiration of HashMap in Redis python?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, redis, hashmap

I want to store the following hash map in redis:

```
"data": {
       "name": "XYZ",
       "age": 22,
       "address": "a-z"
}
```

I want this whole hash map (with the given key) to expire in time, let's say 72 hours.

How do I use `ttl/expire` function in python?

Comment: Have you got any code yet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks,

Following is what I want to do, I guess it is right:

```
def put_data(name, key, value):  
    import redis  
    r = Redis.get_connection()  
    ttl = datetime.today() + timedelta(hours=72)  
    r.hset(name=name, key=key, value=value)  
    r.expire(name=name, time=ttl)
```

Comment: Thanks. Small comment
`r.expire(name=hash_name, time=ttl)` should be `r.expire(name=name, time=ttl)` for consistency purposes. And on the same page ` r.hset(name=name, key=hash_key, value=hash_data)` should be  r.hset(name=name, key=hash_key, value=value)

Answer (score 5):

This is how:

```
redis_client.expire(your_key, time_in_seconds)
```

See the [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.expire).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to store these values and not the top level dictionary you have shown in the post you would use [hmset](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.hmset) then you would use [expire](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.expire) to set the ttl or [expireat](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.expireat) to set the expiration time on the hashmap